# Error installing zip package of cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am new to cygwin enviroment. when i am trying to install cygwin i get a error MD5 failure and the zip package under archive is not installed. I'm using win 7 ultimate x64.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you have to install using the zip package, but if you download setup.exe from [cygwin.com](http://cygwin.com), then choose the "install from internet" option at runtime, then installation should be much smoother.

if you have any problems with MD5 sums doing it that way, try selecting another mirror.